# What's the purpose of `Case` with VBA's `Select` statement?

Tags: vba, syntax

VBA has a `Select` statement that chooses which code to run based on a value (much like `switch` in C-style languages).  The syntax for this statement looks like:

```
Select Case x
    Case 1
        'do one thing
    Case 2
        'do a different thing
End Select
```

What is the purpose of the `Case` right after `Select`?  Alternatively, what is the meaning of `Select` without `Case`?

Comment: I think the syntax tag says it all. This is just the syntax choosen by the language designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `Select` statement in VBA. There is a [`Select Case` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Therefore, strictly speaking, the answers to your questions are: There is none, and there is none.

It's a bit like asking what is the meaning of `Pri` without `nt` and vice-versa... There is no particularly exciting answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a syntactical requirement of the `Select Case` statement in VBA: [Select Case Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278665.aspx)

`Select` without `Case` will cause a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Without the various `Case` statements, the VBA compiler would not be able to differentiate between the code that you would want executed for each situation.

Imagine your code without the case statements:

```
Select Case x

     'do one thing

     'do a different thing
End Select
```

How do you know when to do which thing?

You can do the same thing as the Select Case statement with If statements

```
If x Then
     'do one thing
ElseIf x Then
     'do a different thing
End If
```

What if we got rid of the If statements? It wouldn't work the way you wanted it to.

**Like others have said, the Case statement is just a necessary part of VBA.**

Here's link that provides a good overview of the Select Case Statement along with some examples: [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about.  I'm asking about why VBA wouldn't have you write `Select x` instead of `Select Case x`.

Comment: Sorry about that! I misread your. I thought you were asking about the Select Case statement in general.